# Writing a trigger to prevent a deletion

Tags: mysql

I have the following set of tables about a set of performers, the activities they perform and the concerts at which they perform those activities. I want to write a trigger that prevents the deletion of a row from the PERFORMERS table, when the performer in question is the last performer(by date) of the particular activity that he/she is performing. Note that even though a single performer only performs
a unique activity, a given activity can be performed by a number of performers.

```
CREATE TABLE Activities (
ActivityID int NOT NULL,
ActivityName char(30) NOT NULL default 'charity',
PRIMARY KEY (ActivityID)
);

CREATE TABLE Performers (
  PerformerID int NOT NULL default '0',
  PerformerName char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  Street char(20) NOT NULL default '',
  City char(15) NOT NULL default '',
  State char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  Zip int NOT NULL default '0',
  ActivityID int default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (PerformerID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ActivityID) REFERENCES Activities(ActivityID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE Concerts (
  PerformerID int NOT NULL default '0',
  ArenaID int NOT NULL default '0',
  ConcertDate datetime NOT NULL default '2006-01-01',
  TicketPrice int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (PerformerID,ArenaID),
  FOREIGN KEY (PerformerID) REFERENCES Performers(PerformerID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (ArenaID) REFERENCES Arenas(ArenaID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

I have set up the following trigger, but can't think of how to really put the logic into the code. That is, how I do I check whether the performer on which the deletion is being performed is the last performer to perform the activity that he performs ?

```
DELIMETER //

CREATE TRIGGER deletePerformer
BEFORE DELETE 
ON PERFORMERS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
/*
check whether this performer is the last to perform his activity
if not allow delete
else prevent delete
*/
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Delete not allowed';
END;//

DELIMETER;
```

Comment: To abort a procedure use `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Delete not allowed';`

Comment: @juergend I know that should be added to the trigger. But my problem is actually on how to check whether the performer on which the delete is being performed is the last performer to perform a particular activity.

Comment: Why don't you just change the question to focus on the query then?

Comment: Updated the question and the trigger body.